# POST request via HTTPS - which library?

Tags: c++, c, http, post, https

currently I'm doing POST-requests via HTTP which is quite easy:
- open network connection to server
- send some ASCII-data according to HTTP POST specification
- receive ASCII-data and parse them

Now I want to do the same but via a secure HTTPS-connection and by using a custom, **locally provided root-certificate**. Since I do not want to do the whole key exchange/encryption handling manually: what library could I use for this? It should be open source, available for Windows and Linux and should come with a non-restrictive license (some LGPL-type or GPL with linking exception).

Any recommendations for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An obvious choice is [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/). Handles HTTP for you, as well as HTTPS via OpenSSL or GnuTLS; easy to use; works on a wide variety of operating systems; MIT licensed.